# Sequential convergence in non-standard analysis

Tags: real-analysis, nonstandard-analysis

Is the following way of defining sequential convergence correct? 
The real sequence $(x_n)$ converges to a real number $L$ if the hyperreal number $(x_1 - L, x_2-L, x_3-L,\ldots )$ is an infinitesimal.

Comment: .....or if it's zero, depending on whether or not  you include 0 among the infinitesimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are working within the ultrafilter approach to nonstandard-analysis. Then this does not work; see for instance:

Let $U$ be the ultrafilter (on $\mathbb{N}$) corresponding to said hyperreal system. Let $A$ be an infinite but not cofinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ which belongs to $U$.
Such a set exists: either $2\mathbb{N}$ or $2\mathbb{N}+1$ is an example.

Let $x: \mathbb{N}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the sequence such that $x(n) = L + \frac{1}{n}$ if $n-1 \in A$ and $x(n) = L+1$ otherwise.
Then $[(x_1-L,x_2-L,...)]$ is an infinitesimal despite the fact that $x$ does not converge to $L$.

The reciprocal is true however: if the sequence converges to $L$, the described hyperreal number is infinitesimal.

Answer (score 0):

In Internal Set Theory, the usual notion is *near covergence*. A sequence $\{x_n\}$ nearly converges to a real number $c$ if $|x_k - c|$ is infinitesimal whenever $k$ is nonstandard.

It is straightforward to show that all standard sequences converge (in the classical sense) if and only if they nearly converge.

Comment: pash, I don't think the OP is working with nonstandard indices.

Comment: What references call this near convergence?

Comment: @MikhailKatz, no, but I think it's useful to offer the Nelsonian approach, even if the question takes a Robinsonian perspective.

Comment: @GPhys, most of the standard IST references. The terminology is Nelson's—he consistently uses the modifiers *near* and *nearly* for analogues of classical definitions that may differ for nonstandard objecets but which are equivalent for standard objects. If you're looking for an easy introduction to the axiomatic approach, I recommend Alain Robert's [*Nonstandard Analysis*](https://www.amazon.com/Nonstandard-Analysis-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486432793) from Dover.

Comment: @pash Can you list some? Alain and the Nelson articles I've read don't use it, but I think Nelson changed his terminology a lot through the years. (I'm asking just to find the references I haven't read, so please share!)

Comment: @GPhys, by "Alain" you probably mean "Robert".

Comment: @Gphys, I had in mind mainly the literature developing Nelson's "radically elementary" treatment of probability theory based on nonstandard, finite spaces. See Nelson's [*Radically Elementary Probability Theory*](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enelson/books/rept.pdf) [PDF], and, e.g., Geyer's perpetually in progress [*Radically Elementary Probability and Statistics*](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/nsa/o.pdf) [PDF], and Herzberg's [*Stochastic Calculus with Infinitesimals*](https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Calculus-Infinitesimals-Lecture-Mathematics/dp/3642331483) [Amazon].